# How to implement 3d texturing in OpenGL 3.3

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, textures

So I have just realized that the code I was working on for 3d textures was for OpenGL 1.1 or something and is no longer supported in OpenGL 3.3. Is there another way to do this without glTexture3D? Perhaps through a library or another function in OpenGL 3.3 that I do not know about?

EDIT:
I am not sure where I read that 3d texturing was taken out of OpenGL in newer versions (been googling a lot today), but consider this:

I have been following the tutorial/guide [here](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL%3aTutorials:3D_Textures). The program compiles without a hitch. Now read the following quote from the article:

> The potential exists that the environment the program is being run on does not support 3D texturing, which would cause us to get a NULL address back, and attempting to use a NULL pointer is A Bad Thing so make sure to check for it and respond appropriately (the provided example exits with an error).

That quote is referring to the following function:

```
glTexImage3D = (PFNGLTEXIMAGE3DPROC) wglGetProcAddress("glTexImage3D");
```

When running my program on my computer (which has OpenGL 3.3) that same function returns null for me. When my friend runs it on his computer (which has OpenGL 1.2) it does not return null.

Comment: I can't find/don't know of any info about volume textures being deprecated or any support dropped. Could you provide a link, please?

Comment: ... it's not deprecated http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glTexImage3D.xml

Comment: My guess is that your context creation is wrong. On recent OpenGL it's horribly messy : http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context#Proper_Context_Creation . Consider using GLFW or similar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way one uploads 3D textures has not changes since OpenGL-1.2. The functions for this are still named

- `glTexImage3D`
- `glTexSubImage3D`
- `glCopyTexSubImage3D`